# How to print on file in reverse order with process chain?

Tags: c, algorithm, process

I have this exercise: every process must print on file a sentence, but in reverse order.
So, if the process chain is P1->P2->....->Pn, Pn prints on file, then Pn-1, and so on...
I'm stuck with this...
Any idea?

Comment: fork in a loop.  wait for the child to finish, then print.

Comment: A stack would work as well.  Each process pushes its output onto the stack, then print the stack.  One use for a stack is to reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you're looking for a depth first search (DFS) approach here, since you need to process the child first rather than the parent process. For DFS, the easiest way to implement it would be using a recursive stack. A simplified algorithm would be

```py
def process_chain(node):
    if node has child:
        process_chain(child)
    print(node.value)   #or whatever processing you need to do on the node
    return

process_chain(P1)
```